# Which mirrorless system should I pick for M-mount lenses (Leica / Zeiss ZM)

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lens-adapter, mirrorless, m-mount

Which Mirrorless system should I pick for shooting with Leica M and Zeiss ZM glass? And why?

My priorities:

- Manual focusing assists (can be rangefinder system, can be focus peaking, I hate picture-in-picture though)
- Good viewfinder (preferably build-in, either OVF or EVF, doesn't make much difference for me - I worked with both, enjoyed both)
- Good RAW image quality at low ISOs (don't care about anything above ISO400)
- Lightroom-integrated workflow (suppose I can pass with DXO or something else though)
- High-quality adaptors (don't want anything plastic or some cheap chinese aluminium)

What I don't care about:

- Autofocus
- JPG image quality, build-in raw processing or anything that's applied to JPGs only. I'm a RAW shooter.
- Native glass, or adaptors for other bayonets.
- Mirrorless with sensors from Point & Shoot cameras (Pentax Q, Nikon 1, etc.)

I can't afford Leica. Thought about buying Zeiss Ikon, but going fully into a film photography might limit me in some types of the shooting I do, so it went down in priority, perhaps one day when I get enough cash I'll go for it as a secondary camera as well... it's gorgeous. Pure photography tool unlike these mirrorless toys. But for a time being it seems like I could use a mirrorless so: what's your advice?

What are the options on a market?
Are there any particular strong or weak points of any system you propose?
How they perform with M-mount glass? Are there any artefacts?
Is there any specific camera you'd recommend? What would be it's weak points?

Comment: What is picture-in-picture focus assist?

Comment: @Unapiedra Take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=nncLryFfkWA#t=84s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll certainly want the largest sensor you can get your hands on. Currently APS-C mirrorless systems are available from Sony, Fuji and Canon and Samsung. I wouldn't choose Canon as it's the least mature system with only one camera body, which lacks any sort of viewfinder. Samsung is out, as the flange focal distance is 25mm, only 2mm shorter than M mount, so not enough space for an adaptor.

Personally I would go with Sony and chose the NEX6. Only 16MP compared to it's 24MP but can cope with wide rangefinder lenses without colour shifts in the corners. The sensor has great dynamic range, the body has a built in high resolution electronic viewfinder and the camera features focus peaking for easier manual focus.

The Fuji X-Pro1 is a strong contender, with an [innovative colour filter array](http://fujifilm-x.com/x-pro1/en/about/sensor/index.html) and no AA filter on the sensor. However you might have problems using lightroom due to the unconventional CFA needing a non-standard demosaicing algorithm.

### Looking forward

The ultimate mirrorless camera has yet to be released. All models have their quirks, and all models (other than the Leicas) are limited to APS-C size sensors. However this is set to change.

Sony are widely believed to be working on a full frame version of the NEX which will really make the M-mount lenses shine. Fuji have vaguely hinted at doing the same, however Sony have actually made one full frame E mount video camera, and one full frame mirrorless compact (albeit with fixed lens). Estimated date for the full frame NEX stills camera is early 2014.

With this in mind you may want to wait a bit, or get one of the current bodies as a stopgap.

Metabones make a full frame adaptor for NEX in the form of a focal reducer that projects a full frame image onto the APS-C sensor, however it wont work on rangefinder lenses due to the short flange focal distance for the M mount.

Comment: Saving other people to look it up: CFA = Colour Filter Array

Comment: @Matt Grum - 
What about [color fringing](http://www.stevehuffphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/nexcolorshift-680x453.jpg) and color shifts on NEX from Leica glass? Heard some really bad opinions about NEX7 on that mater. "_Metabones make a full frame adaptor for NEX in the form of a focal reducer that projects a full frame image onto the APS-C sensor_" - Yea, been through that, seen the pictures, sorry, marketing gimmicks don't work on me.

Comment: @MarcinWolny The SB isn't a marketing gimmick, but it's more for video work. It wont take M mount lenses anyway. Color shifts are a problem with the NEX7 when using wide angle rangefinder lenses. The  NEX6 (sort of successor to the 7, also has built in EVF) is reportedly much better in this regard. Short backfocus lenses have always been a problem for digital sensors due to the oblique angles of incidence. Finally, the ultimate mirrorless camera has yet to be produced (but may be soon), so you may have to get an intermediate body in the meantime.

Comment: @MattGrum it's quite weird that the issue occurs only with NEX7 though, especially in regards of color shift. As Steve Huff posted - Ricoh for example never had such issues. Even though it too uses the APS-C CMOS sensor. And to make it even more fun [it looks like there's color shift not only at the edges, but also at different apertures](http://diglloyd.com/blog/2012/20120105_2-SonyNEX7-ColorBalance.html) which makes it rather pointless to buy. I wonder what other cameras have similar issues with M-glass, especially aperture-related color shifts.?

Comment: Would you change anything about your answer a year later?  Sony now has a FF for example.

Answer (score 5):

*Consider this an addendum to Matt's answer which is quite sound to me.*

Given your circumstances, I would strongly lean towards the Fuji system. Since you do not care about native lenses, you will avoid Fuji's biggest shortcoming which is a minimal set of native lenses. Image quality is absolutely top-notch with both the X-Pro1 and X-E1.

My preference is easily for the [Fuji X-E1 which I reviewed last week](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/fuji/xe1/review). It is more compact and has a sharper 2.4 megapixels electronic-only viewfinder. The OVF mode on the X-Pro1 was completely useless to me because I frame exactly and there are no 100% coverage lines, plus parallax made framing very approximate. As a bonus the X-E1 is a lot cheaper.

Most importantly in your case is that Fuji makes their own electronic [Leica M-mount adapter](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/digital_cameras/accessories/lens/mount/fujifilm_m_mount_adapter/). You can configure it for your different lenses and then easily switch between lenses using the button the adapter. The MF-assist though is PIP which you said you don't like though.

Comment: What about the artifacts reported when converting Fuji RAW files with Adobe products: http://diglloyd.com/blog/2012/20120922_1-Fuji-XPro1-Leica135.html is there a fix out there? I've been tempted by the X system but things like that put me off.

Comment: Yikes that is scary! For now, I'd stick Fuji's implementation and I would guess this is only a temporary problem. It is in the best interest of both Adobe and Fuji to make this work. As I understand it, it is now in Adobe's court since Fuji said they have sent all the necessary information to Adobe. If you do not need a new system right now, waiting would not be bad as I *suspect* the X-E2 will have Phase-Detection AF as well.

Comment: The bright-lines OVF will be closer to working with a real Leica rangefinder, FWIW, so it's nice to have the option.

Comment: I got an X-E1 with Fuji M adapter this weekend and feel that I should add a caveat to the advice above: Not all M mount lenses work with the Fuji adapter. It has electronic connections to the camera, which means that its smallest diameter is a bit smaller than the M mount, which means that you cannot use lenses with a very large rear element. (You can't use lenses that poke deeply into the camera house either, but that is more immediately apparent.) The rear element diameter restriction is more nasty because it means that good lenses like the VC Nokton 35/1.2 can't be mounted.

Comment: (continued from above...) I have the Nokton 35/1.2, a 50mm DR Summicron and a 35/2.8 Jupiter-12, among others; the Nokton won't fit because of the rear element diameter and the two others because they protrude too far into the camera body. I'm getting a third-party adapter now, to get at least the Nokton to fit. Don't know if it will help the other two. For now I am using a goggled 35/2.8 Summaron as my "50 mm" lens, which looks absolutely idiotic on the camera but which works quite well indeed :)

Comment: Indeed, in case it was not clear, see the link in my answer for the complete list of compatible lenses as tested by Fuji.

Comment: @StaaleS TBH: Fuji seems like a most interesting option, especially because of dedicated adapter and bodies actually supporting EXIF info about lens used (which would be a GREAT help for photo-archiving). So here are two questions: 1. Does Fuji has got any issues with colors while using M-glass? I'm especially curious about shifts with bright lenses wide open, and wide angle lenses (24-18mm) being wide open. 2. Is Fuji going to release any FF camera this year? Is Fuji bayonet even compatible with Full Frame?

Comment: EXIF is correct for adapted lenses, assuming that you go into the menu system and tell the camera which focal lens you are using whenevery you change lens! Which you may or may not do; I tend to forget to do it - 1. Wide-angles are usually the most problematic, and it is reported as an issue on all relevant digital cameras whether Fuji, Sony or Leica. My Voigtländer 15mm seems to behave reasonably well as far as I can tell. 2 - A Fuji FF would need a different bayonet I think.

Comment: @StaaleS - Thanks a lot. If it's fine with 15mm then it's more than good enough - I'll most likely won't be going below 18mm in any foreseeable future. It's a shame though that the FF sensor cannot be used with Fuji X bayonet. I had a chance to play with X-PRO 1 and ergonomics seem to be good, image quality great, AF worst I ever seen, and in the end: Seems like a great camera for my needs, so any declaration on releasing FF body with current bayonet would make it hit my wishlist instantly.

Comment: I think I'll pass for a moment, see if Fuji releases any XPRO successor (I read it should hit stores this year - if it'll have OVF then most likely that's the camera I'll end up with) or roadmap for FF system. But so far X-mount seems like a most attractive of all for using M-mount lenses.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at the Ricoh GXR system. It is fantastic to use, and the M Mount module is optimised for Leica mount lenses due to the design of the sensor, which means perfect sharpness into corners, and no colour shifts.

Today you can pick up bodies, EVF and M mounts very cheaply, and compile a system excluding glass for about £ 500.

Why?

Build quality,
Optimised sensor,
100% viewfinder and no EVF blur,
2 types of Focus peaking and magnification. 
Accurate focusing & silent shutter,
Excellent customisable ergos,
Extremely good defn/ sharpness at high ISOs,
No AA filter

Why not?

Slow start up,
Evident noise, film-like in nature, at high ISOs.
Only 12 MP?
Probably end of the road for the GXR system.

Comment: GXR doesn't really qualify as a "mirrorless system" does it? It's just one body released in 2009 with no successor nor any known plans from Ricoh. I also don't think that the "Build quality" is any advantage of it. It's looks like Frankencamera with rather horrific ergonomics. So even if it's made fully of titanium and weather-sealed - I still would have a lot of trouble thinking about it as something having good build quality.

Comment: Sure. It's kind of an odd system, but I think it qualifies, and it's the only non-Leica option to offer a native M-mount.

Comment: @mattdm Native? I thought it needs M-mount module to use Leica glass. Can you point me in the right direction for a native M-mount version? Cause I cannot find it myself. :(

Comment: @MarcinWolny It's a unique system. The module isn't an adapter, but rather a complete unit with the mount and a sensor designed to match.

Comment: @mattdm oh, ok, I get what you mean now. Thought that Ricoh actually developed native M-mount camera I haven't heard about. Well, I think I'll pass on GXR. Major reason being that it's a blind investment in a system that might have no future. I seen some of the samples though and they look really nice, another thing being that Ricoh seems to managed to do something many failed - a sensor that actually works well with Leica M glass. Problem is that it's only 12 MPx on rather ancient sensor (in terms of DR, etc.) and body leaves much to wish for. Thanks for mentioning it though!

Comment: @MarcinWolny, Maybe 'roadmap' ended with the acquisition of Pentax by Ricoh. However, to say the ergonomics are horrible is to highlight that you've not used it for any meaningful amount of time. Ergonomics are simply fantastic - way better than Leica X1, X100, X-E1 - and make using the system with the A12 M Mount an absolute joy. The sensor, as mattdm points out, is highly optimised for M lenses and it works beautifully. White balance is perfect. Focus peaking with centre magnification is excellent. Noise is film-grain like above ISO 600. GXR is definitely, definitionally, 100% 'mirrorless'.

Comment: @MarcinWolny, to continue, I don't see the use of a separate sensor module designed ground-up for leica M glass, that fits into a sensorless body, as obviating the defn of a 'mirrorless' camera. Surely your aesthetic issues are separate issues? Personally I like the anonymous design and solid construction (and understand that others don't!) as it creates an excellent feel & balance for a photographic tool, whilst being totally silent when taking photos and therefore perfect for candid portraits. AND, THE LACK OF A MIRROR MEANS IT'LL RELIABLY TAKE TACK SHARP IMAGES HANDHELD AT 1/30TH SEC.

Comment: @Nick hehe, I wouldn't make such a huge advantage from lack of the mirror, especially because **with M Mount you never have mirror** so there's nothing to put against it. As for the GXR being mirrorless, well, it is, but it's very unconventional with sensor that basically stick's out of the body and was made more as an afterthought with no plans for continuation then anything else. And that's basically also my major issue with the ergonomics of it - despite of what you say:It's not seamless, and I would hardly say that it's better in ergonomics then Leica or Fuji X-E1. But It's very subjective

Answer (score -1):

Well to give you details canon has not produced any official leica or zeiss adaptors for eos m. Also eos m does not have viewfinder but an external hotshoe viewfinder sold separately. The image quality is one of the best among others in terms of image overall contrast and color values. To be honest using the peak quality lenses with low quality bodies(according to lens) is not what I recommend. for those lenses your best choice -though you're telling expensive- is leica-m. For last, I have experienced out of focus results in prime lenses with adaptors in different brand experiments which are canon, nikon and sony using leica and zeiss lenses. Which are inevitable because of body(+processor) - lens compatiblity. Those occur in higher percents as the min f stop of the prime lens decraeses.

Comment: "_The important part I want to point out is that canon and nikon are the pioneers in dslr and their imaging technologies are far beyond any other_" - no offense man, but I used bit more brands then you did, and this sentence you just made here asks for only one replay: Pure BS. One of these BSs that you can see only from most brand-blinded people.

Comment: And Nikon has historically used Sony-manufactured sensors!

Comment: to Marcin, to be honest probably you could have used more then me if you are a field tester in any of the review companies and dont know if this is your profession or not. Well here are the [TIPA Awards 2012](http://www.tipa.com/english/XXII_tipa_awards_2012_13042012103433.php?iExpand1=70), also I'm using mkIII and mkII and have tried many other so called similar machines. Canon also has the best customer support with CPN. anyways Most of the photo artists, visual artists, fashion and portrait photographer are using canon. Those are my points and your points are BS lol.

Comment: To MikeW sorry mate but Intel makes processors, Mac does computers, your argument is invalid. I have used sony too, alpha is literally useless.

Comment: @YiğitHürUlaş I'd suggest to be les fanatic about the gear. And tipa awards are joke, everyone aware know that. It's like if you'd call a Ken Rockwell as an authority here. Please, take a look at [FAQ](http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq) and be aware that **we do not discuss here which brand is the best**.

Comment: @MarcinWolny please inform me if the question is not asking about brand. if it is not, sorry my bad. because last time I checked it was _"Which mirrorless system should I pick for M-mount lenses (Leica / Zeiss ZM)"_ my vote here is on canon, unlike you my friend, I take tipa awards, my job and favourite hobby seriously and for your information it is not fanatism but more like passion. I love the way my cameras answer to my demands. I wont take this conversation any further not to contaminate the main subject. If you like, you can vote each of my reviews and answers down. Kind regards,

Comment: @YiğitHürUlaş again - read the FAQ. Stackexchange is not a place to discuss which brand is the best. And what you are doing is exactly that - talking crap through brand loyalty about how Canon and Nikon rule the photography world. I'm not interested in that. I'm interested in getting a camera that meets my expectations and works best with Leica M glass. So far you haven't gave any information on how supportingly Canon meets any of these nor focused around any of priorities nor gave info about any weak points nor answered any concerns about artefacts. (to be continued)

Comment: (continuing) All I see is "_I'm passionate_", "_I'm sererious photographer_", "_I'm experienced_", "_canon and nikon are the pioneers in dslr_", "_artist around the world choses Canon_", "_canon-m image quality is pretty close to 3 years old camera_". I'm not interested in who you are, how you love canon, who uses Canon, and how Canon mirrorless image quality is close to the Canon DSLR image quality, both of which use canon sensors from same generation. It doesn't have anything to deal with a topic.

Comment: If you want to help - edit your question to answer questions I asked in last paragraph (and please, read it whole, not just a headline), as well as try to address my priorities list. Because otherwise you look like noone else then one of these Canon trolls that don't care about photography but rather who uses their gear and how "pro" is it on "prosness" scale (if such thing even exists). I don't want to have anything to deal with that.

Comment: I never ment to talk big and havent realized I have done so. anyways my recommendations and review on eos m are as changed in the answer. And your arrogent "BS" comment pushed me a bit to arrogence that I can confess.